Cyclic Voltammetry for a Capacitor - Positive Current, Potential is decreasing?

In the boxed red region, why is the potential decreasing when the current is still positive? To my understanding, when the current is still positive (i.e. not changing direction), the capacitor will accumulate more and more charge.
Source: https://www.gamry.com/application-notes/battery-research/testing-electrochemical-capacitors-cyclic-voltammetry-leakage-current/ (My experimental data (and other sources) show the same pattern.)

I would suggest to study the interpretation of standard cyclic voltammograms  before analyzing more complex CVs. Provide a reference whenever you take figures from somewhere so that people can understand the background of a figure more. This figure has been taken from https://www.gamry.com/application-notes/battery-research/testing-electrochemical-capacitors-cyclic-voltammetry-leakage-current/

Also why a capacitor gives a rectangular CV is addressed here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36546/why-does-an-ideal-capacitor-give-rise-to-a-rectangular-cyclic-voltammogram-cv

Did you read the answer in the Electronics Stack Exchange? It answers your question.

@ACR Yes, the first answer says "The current suddenly changes but with little or no change in voltage, resulting in vertical lines." My question is regarding this "little change in voltage" - it decreases a tiny bit while current is still positive. Although it happen suddenly, why does the graph show this? In the second answer in the link you sent me above, it shows a simulation where the voltammogram always has a positive current when the voltage is increasing.
